# Rails inline pdf attachment in email can not display on Iphone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iphone, pdf, email-attachments

I have successfully added pdf file as inline attachment to email. My problem is, When I add png file I can show that file inline as;

```
<%= image_tag attachments['logo.png'].url, :style => "display: block; width: 80px;"  %>
```

and in my mailer;

```
attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.read(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/logo.png'))
```

When I add as pdf;

```
attachments.inline['Delivery_Document.pdf'] = File.read(Rails.root.join('app/assets/folder/Delivery_Document.pdf'))
```

in my mailer it works on the desktop, I can see the attachment.

But when I look at the same email from iphone, I can not see the attachment. I think it is because I do not add inline as

```
<%= image_tag attachments['logo.png'].url, :style => "display: block; width: 80px;"  %>
```

But how can I add pdf file like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add pdf as attachment not inline attachment.

```
attachments['Delivery_Document.pdf'] = File.read(Rails.root.join('app/assets/folder/Delivery_Document.pdf'))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can not see the attachment on iphone

Comment: do you add other attachments with "pdf" to email? Try to use only attachments without inline because of [bug](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2686)

Comment: No, I only have 1 pdf attachment. I added as you wrote, I can see the attachment on desktop but not on smart phone.

Comment: Dou you have [such message](https://forums.adobe.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/102-4621-16-645362/DownloadFullMessage2.png) in your email?